# How to create instance of model instance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build an API/library/package in JavaScript where developers can create an instance of a model, then create instances of objects based on that model.

For example a popular example of this would be Mongoose:

```
const mongoose = ...
const modelA = new mongoose.model("Cat", {name: String});
const modelB = mongoose.model("Cat2", {name: String});

const cat = new modelA({name: "Tom"});
const catB = new modelB({name: "Smith"});
```

---

So the question is almost two fold. The first, how can I expose a method (`model`) that supports the `new` keyword to create an instance or not?

```
class Model {
    constructor(name, schema) {
        this.name = name;
        // ...
    }
}

module.exports = (...args) => new Model(...args);
```

Currently in my library, I have something like the code above, which allows for `api.model`, but not `new api.model`. Is there a way to adjust this so that I can allow users of the library to use either syntax option?

---

Second, how can I support users of this package to create an instance of the model instance?

The thing that gets returned from creating a new model is an instance of `Model`, but the consumer of this library can't then create an instance of that since it's just an object and can't be used to create a new instance of something based on itself.

---

Really aiming to get the interface of this API to be very similar to Mongoose from the consumer of this library's perspective. So not looking for solutions that require the consumer of the library to change the syntax from what I posted.

Comment: *"The first, how can I expose a method (model) that supports the new keyword to create an instance or not?"* Use a normal function (constructor), not a `class`. Functions are callable and constructable. Functions created from `class`es are only constructable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little confused by this question. Could you elaborate a little more if this doesn't answer your question.

I would also note that you should be extremely (and I mean EXTREMELY) careful with giving users this much power. Especially if you will be letting them directly interact with your DB in the example you provider. Im still not entire sure why you would want to do this and would consider other options first.

Anyway that being said, as to the whole creating instances of an instance, that is totally possible. Objects are objects are objects. The class you created is an object, which creates objects. In Javascript we only really have prototypal inheritance. So lets say you have and instance of a class, and you want to create a unqiue instance of that instance you can use `Object.create(instance)`. This with return you an object, with its prototype pointing to the `instance` you originally passed.

For the first part of your question, still a little confused on the wording but I'm assuming that you want to create a way for users to create a new instance of the model class. Im also assuming that there will be alot more functionality on this model class. I would recommend creating a API class to interact and 'manage' these models. So you would create a new class that has a method on it which when run invokes `new Model(args)`. Let me know if that was what you were looking for.

Alright - So if you wanna use both you could use a function constructor:

```
function SomeClass() {
  someObj = {};
  someObj.blah = 'a';
  someObj.func = function() {
    console.log(this.blah);
  }
  return someObj;
}
```

You could use this with `new SomeClass()` and `SomeClass()`

Comment: Also for the love of god please make sure that you don't let anyone store whatever they want, and doesn't let other users render dynamic data from other users models. Again whole thing sounds super risky. Best of luck

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough. By API I don't mean web API where clients interact with it, I mean an API/library that developers use to help with their development. So there is 0 risk for developers interacting with my DB. They'll be using this library/package to interact with their own systems. I'll work on updating the question now with further detail and clarification.

Comment: Ahh you specifically your very set on using the new syntax ?

Comment: Wait why don't you just export Model ? Then they could use new Model ??

Comment: `TypeError: Class constructor Model cannot be invoked without 'new'`. You are required to use the `new` keyword at that point. There isn't a way to use both syntax versions.

Comment: Ok awesome! And I was able to create an instance of that instance by just returning a function, that I added a property to with the `this` of the outer function. Thanks so much! I thought that `class` was just a drop in replacement for a function constructor, but it really isn't. Thanks for your help!